# Disable submit button but not getting post data

Tags: php

I have the following code:

```
<?php
$post_test = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'test');
if (isset($post_test)) {
    echo 'has data';
    // ********************
    // it is not going here
    // ********************
}

<form role="form" action="" method="post">
    // some form fields here
    <button type="submit" name="test" class="form-button" onclick="this.form.submit(); this.disabled=true; ">Send</button>
</form>
```

I want to disable the button when i submit. But it is not going inside the  php code I highlighted above and there's no data.  So I resorted to this just to fake the disabling:

```
<form role="form" action="" method="post">
    <button type="submit" name="test" class="form-button" onclick="this.className='button-disabled'; this.innerHTML='Sending...'; ">Send</button>
</form>
```

Please advise.

**Updated**

```
<?php
$post_test = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'test');
if (isset($post_test)) {
    echo 'has data';
    // ********************
    // it is not going here
    // ********************
}
?>    

<form role="form" action="" method="post">
    // some form fields here
    <button type="submit" name="test" value="1" class="form-button" onclick="this.form.submit(); this.disabled=true; this.className='button-disabled'; this.innerHTML='Sending...'; ">Send</button>
</form>
```

Comment: You don't have a `value` attribute in your button. So the resulting `POST` is empty. Simply add `value="1"` to your button and the POST will work

Comment: I added the value in button but still it won't go through.

Comment: I tested your code and just by adding `value="1"` to the button the `if` at the beginning is entered correctly. Please share your updated code.

Comment: i updated the code... still not working

Comment: remove the `this.form.submit();` since that's already a submit button. And try only onclick="this.className='button-disabled'; this.innerHTML='Sending...'; "

Comment: if i remove it and remove the disabled=true, then it will allow me to click the button twice which i am trying to prevent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of performing the check on the `name` of the submit button, create an hidden element with name test and value 1.

```
<form role="form" action="" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="test" value="1" />
    <button type="submit" class="form-button" onmouseup="this.form.submit();  this.disabled=true; this.className='button-disabled'; this.innerHTML='Sending...'; ">Send</button>
</form>
```